# Error de codificación UTF-8 en XML firmado en .NET

Tags: .net, xml, utf-8, firma-digital

Estoy generando un archivo XML firmado con información de facturas, para el envío al servicio TicketBAI de la diputación foral de Guipuzkoa.
El programa está desarrollado sobre .NET y para generar la firma utilizo la librería [FirmaXadesNet](https://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ctt/verPestanaGeneral.htm?idIniciativa=firmaxadesnet).
El problema es que en ocasiones TicketBAI rechaza los envíos porque la codificación UTF-8 no es correcta.
Los pasos para generar este archivo son:

- Se genera un archivo XML en una carpeta con los datos da la factura.
- Se lee el archivo generado y se firma y graba con la librería FirmaXadesNet.
- Se lee el archivo firmado y se envía.

Los archivos generados los abro con el editor Notepad++ y me indica que la codificación es UTF-8. Consulto esos mismos archivos con el visor hexadecimal y veo que los caracteres están correctamente codificados.
¿Cuál puede ser el error?