# Errores de codificación UTF-8 en archivos XML firmados en .NET

Tags: .net, xml, utf-8, firma-digital

Estoy enviando archivos XML firmados al servicio TicketBAI de la diputación foral de Guipuzkoa.
El desarrollo de la aplicación está hecho en VB.Net utilizando NET Framework 4.8. Para generar la firma utilizo la librería FirmaXadesNet (https://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ctt/verPestanaGeneral.htm?idIniciativa=firmaxadesnet) y RestSharp para los envíos.
El problema es que algunos de los envíos son rechazados por errores de codificación, cuando contienen algún carácter acentuado, por ejemplo.

El primer paso es generar el archivo XML. Este es el código:

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(TicketBai))
Dim writer As New StreamWriter(arcXML)
serializer.Serialize(writer, oXML)
writer.Close()
```

La clase TicketBai se genera a partir de los xsd de los mensajes del servicio.
Una vez que tengo el archivo XML a enviar lo firmo:

```
params.SignaturePackaging = SignaturePackaging.ENVELOPED
params.DataFormat = New FirmaXadesNet.Signature.Parameters.DataFormat()
params.DataFormat.MimeType = "text/xml"

Dim policyInfo As New SignaturePolicyInfo
With policyInfo
     .PolicyIdentifier = "https://www.gipuzkoa.eus/ticketbai/sinadura"
     .PolicyDigestAlgorithm = DigestMethod.SHA256
     .PolicyHash = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     .PolicyUri = "https://www.gipuzkoa.eus/ticketbai/sinadura"
End With
params.SignaturePolicyInfo = policyInfo
params.Signer = New Signer(certificado)

Dim fs As New FileStream(arcXML, FileMode.Open)
docFirma = servicio.Sign(fs, params)
fs.Close()
fs = Nothing
fs = New FileStream(arcXMLfirmado, FileMode.Create)
docFirma.Save(fs)
fs.Close()
fs = Nothing
```

El último paso es enviar el XML firmado, usando RestSharp:

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader(arcXMLfirmado)
cadXML = sr.ReadToEnd
sr.Close()
sr = Nothing

request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
request.AddHeader("charset", "UTF-8")
request.AddParameter("text/xml", cadXML, ParameterType.RequestBody)

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

cliente = New RestClient(URLapi)
cliente.ClientCertificates = New X509Certificate2Collection
cliente.ClientCertificates.Add(oCertificado)
cliente.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
response = cliente.Execute(request)
```

El resultado del envío es erróneo por un problema de codificación. Si abro el archivo XML firmado con Notepad++ detecta que la codificación es UTF-8. Si lo examino a nivel hexadecimal también parece correctamente codificado. Por ejemplo el carácter "ó" se ve así en hecadecimal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que por lo que he buscado es correcto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe una web que permite diagnosticar errores de firma (https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation), aquí subo los XML firmados erróneos y no detecta ningún error.

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado por las respuestas 
Justo Alonso

Comment: [**No dupliques tus preguntas**](/questions/605488). Edita la anterior pregunta en su lugar, y por cierto, lee el [resumen de la edición](/posts/605488/revisions) a esa pregunta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error de codificación UTF-8 en XML firmado en .NET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605488/error-de-codificaci%c3%b3n-utf-8-en-xml-firmado-en-net)